# Can I have a main Map file in my Activity and share it with the Fragments?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am currently using SharedPreferences for both my preferences and my data. Realizing that getting all of the values for my data out via prefs.getAll() actually gets both of my SharedPreferences which is incredibly annoying.

What is the best route for my data. It is key-value with the keys being dates and the values being floats. (Actually ideally I'd have two floats for every key, but I could traverse two.)

**Can I make a Hash Map in my activity and inflate/deflate as normally and send it to my fragments as I need the data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is asking a few different things, so I'll try answer them all.

For storing data that is too complex for shared preferences, you should look into using an SQLite database. There are some good libraries that make it very simple - check out ActiveAndroid or OrmLite.

If you want to stick with shared preferences, but want to solve the issue of getAll returning the preferences and the data, you can actually create 2 separate sharedpreferences. There is a method getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode) which takes a name. Use the default shared preferences for your preferences, and create a shared preference with a different name for your data.

As for sending data to your fragments, you can use a Bundle. Bundles take all sorts of data, and serializables as well, so that should be no problem. Put your data into a bundle and pass it to your fragment when its instantiated.

Comment: I've been using two different sharedPreferences, but when I use getAll() it retrieves both sets. Can I limit it to just one of my named SharedPreferences?

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that Logcat didn't clear after each restart. Each SharedPreferences with a different string do dump getAll() right. I will just use SharedPreferences. Now to get them to refresh and cache correctly.